# Creating percentage labels in a pie chart

Tags: python, reportlab

I can't seem to find any information on how to display percentage values on the wedges of the pie chart in the context of Reportlab library.

Setting the labels to percentages doesn't work for 2 reasons:
1. Labels need to be strings
2. I still need the proper labels for the legend

Comment: Have you consider plotting the pie chart with other library and append it to ReportLab?

Comment: I have not yet. Would you be able to recommend good libraries for plotting charts?

Comment: I think you won't find anything better than [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/).  I have a script that generates some plots and draws them in a pdf with ReportLab that maybe can help you (altough I don't use nor percentage in the labels (only in the ticks) neither pie charts (only bar charts)).

Comment: Thanks, in the meantime I simply added the percentages as strings to the labels, it does the trick for this report. However, I will check out the plots in matplotlib.